# how do I solve for device not accepting address 73, error -71

Tags: usb, kernel, webcam, camera

I have a network camera, that has a USB port. Every time I plug in the cable  it says (from dmesg):

```
[74305.563588] usb 3-1-port4: attempt power cycle
[74306.167275] usb 3-1.4: new low-speed USB device number 73 using xhci_hcd
[74306.167913] usb 3-1.4: Device not responding to setup address.
[74306.375926] usb 3-1.4: Device not responding to setup address.
[74306.583278] usb 3-1.4: device not accepting address 73, error -71
[74306.663298] usb 3-1.4: new low-speed USB device number 74 using xhci_hcd
[74306.663912] usb 3-1.4: Device not responding to setup address.
[74306.871921] usb 3-1.4: Device not responding to setup address.
[74307.079208] usb 3-1.4: device not accepting address 74, error -71
[74307.079468] usb 3-1-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
```

ok, from what I have read, this is an over current issue. I put the device on a powered (3Amp) usb hub, But I continue to have the same problem.

The network component of the camera is not something I want to use, it has a call back function that streams to the OEM's server, and that is just not cool with me,

what else might I try to get this thing working via USB?
The camera is a guardzilla camera
Ok, I did some more sleuthing, and it might be a Kernel Bug, I was reading [this Launchpad thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1565292), but it wasnt clear to me that there is a patch, or how to fix it.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

and my kernel is:
4.15.0-30-generic

Comment: Did you try to use other cable?

Comment: yes, I tried various cables, and the hub.  It looks like there might be a kernel bug, so Ima update my question

Comment: Also please add output of `lsusb -t` (with camera attached and recognized) to the question.